# Encouraging virtual exchange and independance from hard money?

Tags: economic-theory, currencies

With all the talk of economic sustainability and the dangers of infinite growth how do you think a virtual currency could be used to encourage the trade of virtual goods ? Or possibly a more efficient use of natural resources.

Comment: I think this is more a topic for an essay, rather than a question answerable on a StackExchange.

Comment: It's not unusual that answers on StackExchange grow out to an essay, albeit Quora is even better at that :P Feel free I'd say!

Comment: I can reformulate to something more precise if you wish. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It won't be long before D.H. closes this question. I can bet on that!

Comment: Suggestions are welcome ?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the question. What are the dangers of infinite growth?

Comment: Hi James, the bitcoin stackexchange is really designed for the types of questions where one answer can be clearly labelled "right".  Since this sounds more like an open-ended, everybody-give-your-opinion question, it's not really a good fit for this site and will probably be closed.